# How can i add Custom PHP page on Opencart

Tags: php, content-management-system, opencart

I am trying to implement custom Php and JavaScript base page on open cart actually this is not possible with 'information' feature.any one have idea how can i do this.

Answer (score -1):

I used the tutorial from this website, to add custom pages, I am sure it will work for your expectations  http://www.opencartnews.com/tutorials/creating-a-custom-page-in-opencart-part-1/

Good luck

Comment: Please prefer more inline content over link-only answers that can become broken over time.